# How to send image to server using json

Tags: android, json, internet-explorer, imageview

Anybody please could check my code tell me whats the error in this please.
I m uploading my image to server for the first i upload it show me memory out of error and after that i upload small image don't know where its gone please help me.

here is the code

```
    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

    btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/chatapp/Upload_image_ANDROID/upload_image.php";
    ImageView img= new ImageView(this);

}


@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  if(arg0==btnselectpic)
 {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete actionusing"),1);

   }
        elseif (arg0==uploadButton) {

dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                  uploadFile(imagepath);

             }
           }).start();     
    }

   } 

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

 }
}
  public String getPath(Uri uri) {
         String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
         Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
         int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         return cursor.getString(column_index);
     }

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) 
{


   String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss(); 

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
            }
        }); 

        return 0;

      }
      else
      {
        try { 

           // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("submitType", "PostAd"); 

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

              dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

             }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
              + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                      String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n" ;
                      messageText.setText(msg);
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 });                
            }    

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

       } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

           dialog.dismiss();  
           ex.printStackTrace();

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });

           Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
       } catch (Exception e) {

           dialog.dismiss();  
           e.printStackTrace();

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });
           Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
       }
       dialog.dismiss();       
       return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

This generally has 2 parameters, one is the imagepath and other one is the object of BitmapFactory.Options. Try out by adding the following lines.

```
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath, bmpFactoryOptions);
```